# How to get multiple average values from matching elements in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection like below:

```
[{
    date: '20170721',
    pageUrl: 'page1',
    timing: [{ name: 'dns', duration: 1000 }, { name: 'tcp', duration: 2000 }]
}, {
    date: '20170721',
    pageUrl: 'page2',
    timing: [{ name: 'dns', duration: 1001 }, { name: 'tcp', duration: 1800 }]
}, {
    date: '20170722',
    pageUrl: 'page1',
    timing: [{ name: 'dns', duration: 1021 }, { name: 'tcp', duration: 1700 }]
}, {
    date: '20170722',
    pageUrl: 'page2',
    timing: [{ name: 'dns', duration: 1101 }, { name: 'tcp', duration: 1850 }]
}]
```

and I want the result of average timing of a given page during a given period of date.

For example: I need average timing data of page1, from date 20170701 - 20170731

And the expected output should like:

```
[{
    _id: '20170701',
    dns: <avgDuration>,
    tcp: <avgDuration>
}, {
    _id: '20170702',
    dns: <avgDuration>,
    tcp: <avgDuration>
},
...
]
```

what I tried is, and it didn't work:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'pageUrl': targetPageUrl } },
    { $group: {
        _id: '$date',
        dns: { $avg: '$timing.0.duration' },
        tcp: { $avg: '$timing.1.duration' }
    },
    ...
])
```

Anybody could help? Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the positions are always "fixed" then you can use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/):

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    { '$match': { 'pageUrl': targetPageUrl } },
    { '$group': {
        _id: '$date',
        dns: { '$avg': { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$timing.duration', 0 ] }  },
        tcp: { '$avg': { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$timing.duration', 1 ] } }
    }}
])
```

If they are not actually fixed, then use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to get the matching values:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    { '$match': { 'pageUrl': targetPageUrl } },
    { '$group': {
        _id: '$date',
        dns: { 
          '$avg': {
            '$avg': {
              '$map': {
                'input': { 
                 '$filter': {
                   'input': '$timing',
                   'as': 't',
                   'cond': { '$eq': [ '$$t.name', 'dns' ] }
                 },
                 'as': 't',
                 'in': '$$t.duration'
               } 
            }
          }
        },
        tcp: { 
          '$avg': { 
            '$avg': {
              '$map': {
                'input': { 
                 '$filter': {
                   'input': '$timing',
                   'as': 't',
                   'cond': { '$eq': [ '$$t.name', 'tcp' ] }
                 },
                 'as': 't',
                 'in': '$$t.duration'
               }
            }
          }
        }
    }}
])
```

Being that with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) it actually is possible to have "multiple matches" in an array and "reduce" them down, using [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) in the mode as **"both"** an accumulator and something that takes an "array" as an argument itself. Hence the **"double"** usage of [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/).

Or even using [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) if you feel you really must:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    { '$match': { 'pageUrl': targetPageUrl } },
    { '$group': {
        _id: '$date',
        dns: { 
          '$avg': {
            '$arrayElemAt': [
              '$timing.duration',
              { '$indexOfArray': [ '$timing.name', 'dns' ] }
            ]
          }
        },
        tcp: { 
          '$avg': {
            '$arrayElemAt': [
              '$timing.duration',
              { '$indexOfArray': [ '$timing.name', 'tcp' ] }
            ]
          }
        }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks very much. and may I know why `$timing.0.duration` is not support here?

Comment: @ygjack It never has been. Whilst that form of "dot notation" using an index value is valid for "query" and "projection" it was never valid for the aggregation framework. Only since MongoDB 3.2 has it actually been valid to get an "array" in response to something like `'$timing.duration'`, and at that time of introduction `$arrayElemAt` was also added

Comment: Thanks for the explaination